# Visual Studio Macro

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, crypto++

I am getting LNK2001 errors when trying to use Crypto++. The official advice for this is:

> There are two ways you can deal with this, either change Crypto++ to export those classes, by using the CRYPTOPP_DLL macro, or link with both the DLL export library and a static library that contains the non-DLL classes and functions. The latter can be built by using the "DLL-Import" configuration of the cryptlib project.

It would be preferable to use the first option, and given that I am not experienced in using Visual Studio, I cannot find the location and execution method of the macro.

**In short: Where do I find the macro and how do I execute it?**

Cheers.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/CryptoPPIntegration.aspx

Comment: Use the project's mailing list for additional help: http://www.cryptopp.com/#lists

Answer (score 1):

> In short: Where do I find the macro and how do I execute it?

The macro is `CRYPTOPP_IMPORTS`. You use it when performing dynamic linking on Windows (i.e., the Crypto++ DLL).

You can 'execute' it in one of two ways. First, you can add `#include <cryptopp/dll.h>` to your `stdafx.h`. `dll.h.` defines it, and `dll.h` must be included before any other Crypto++ defines. Second, add it to your project's preprocessor macros. In either case, `CRYPTOPP_IMPORTS` will be defined.

I suspect you have a different error, though. You're probably not including the Crypto++ library (for static linking) or Crypto++ import lib (for dynamic linking) in your project.

Comment: Thank you! Seems release notes are not complete on the configuration interface